# phonegap "new FileTransfer" "is not defined"

Tags: cordova

I get the following error:

```
    ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined
```

when i try to create a new instance:

```
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
```

Developing with PhoneGap on Linux (debian)
Plugins file & file-transfer added of corse

Source:

```
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "text/plain";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "filename";
    options.params = params;

    try {
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
    }

    catch (e) {
        alert("ERR = "+e);
    }
    alert("I = "+imageURI);

    ft.upload(imageURI, http://test.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options, true);
```

URL of server is no valid in this example.

The 1st and 2nd alert are being displayed.

No upload request logged on the server in apache access or error logs

Param imageURI is correct and passed via function param (not part of this source)

PhoneGap Version 3.1.0

Comment: I've reverted your question to the previous version after you deleted it - the whole point is that your question benefits the community. The proper ettiquette would be to post how you solved it as an answer, and then accept it.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I'm using cordova-2.5.0 and it has <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/> in the plugin list.

Answer (score 29):

Did you add the 'file' or 'file-transfer' plugin?

[The Filetransfer plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) is a separate plugin, and you need to add both of them:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Otherwise, the 'FileTransfer' is indeed not defined.

Comment: I would never mind such a small detail. I checked the documentation and it was written there.
Ps: phonegap  plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer

Comment: I did all of that and still firetransfer undefined ,phonegap 3.5

Comment: I have the same error and i've adde the cordova-File-plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands in your phonegap project. And it should resolve the issue on your next build.

Access files on device or network (File API):

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```

See PhoneGap API Documentation - [The Command-line Interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) for a list of the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Please note this plugin doesn't work from the browser, it will throw a “new FileTransfer is not defined” error. Use a real device to test.