# FileTransfer not defined - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to implement file upload in angularjs (in Ionic), but getting some issues. I read a doc following which I ran below commands, while being in project directory -

```
bower install ngCordova
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

Then, I added the required reference in index.html -

```
<!-- ngCordova script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then, I injected the service into my controller -

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AppController', ['$scope', $cordovaFileTransfer', function ($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer)
```

But, when I try to use it like this -

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.upload("server url", "file path", options).then(function(result)...
```

I get an error -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined AppController.js:35     
angular.module.controller.$scope.uploadFile AppController.js:22 (anonymous function)
n.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3 
n.event.add.r.handle jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
```

I am new to AngularJS and not sure what is going wrong here. Am I missing a reference or somethin here? Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1**

Here is how Ionic is initialized -

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

**Edit2**

AppController.js code [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/uCWSfCVChHUvYYFDeYrztG)

Comment: When do you initialize FileTransfer-object first? I read some issues that even if deviceready is fired some plugins might not be present yet. Otherwise try to add file-plugin as well as it states here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544352/phonegap-new-filetransfer-is-not-defined

Comment: @Blauharley I am not too sure what you mean by initializing FileTransfer object. Can you point me to where should I check this?

Comment: Forget this I do not think that's the problem because of your error-message. Did you try it again after installing file-plugin?

Comment: It was by default installed with file-transfer plugin

Comment: So output of file-object does not throw an error and is defined?

Comment: Where should I define it? Sorry I am very new to angular, so can you please point me to how to check it.

Comment: are you accessing this function from a mobile device when you receive this error? because ionic isn't going to make a `FileTransfer` object available to a standard browser....

Comment: @Claies I am on browser. If that is the case, then what should be used for filetransfer?

Comment: @Claies Also, do you have idea what should be the file path in upload function above?

Comment: actually, I'm reading the documentation on this plugin.... can you post a snippet of the code in `AppController.js`?

Comment: @Claies Please see Edit2

Comment: is that code different? you stated that your error was with `var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();` `fileTransfer.upload("server url", "file path", options).then(function(result)...`, and the error says `FileTransfer is not defined AppController.js` but I don't see this anywhere in the link you provided for that file.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was playing around with it. Updated in Edit2 link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just speak for myself but there can be two(ionic: three) reasons why FileTransfer is undefined. And you do not have to define these objects(FileTransfer, File) on your own, they are defined as soon as you installed both-plugins:

1. Issue

   Good approach:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {
      // as soon as this function is called FileTransfer "should" be defined
      console.log(FileTransfer);
   }
   ```

   bad approach:

   ```
   // calling FileTransfer before deviceready
   var f = new FileTransfer();
   ...
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   ...
   ...
   ```
2. Issue

   File-Plugin must be installed as well. After deviceready-function is called File-Object "should" be defined:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {
      // as soon as this function is called File "should" be defined
      console.log(File);
   }
   ```
3. Issue(Ionic)

   When using ionic following command is required to include plugins into a created platform(android, ios, blackberry):

   ```
   ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
   ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
   ```

Sometimes Ionic has got difficulties to build your project properly, in my case either deviceready is not fired at all or building a platform failed on the first place due to compile-issues.

Comment: As I am using Ionic, will it not take care of deviceready? Please see Edit1.

Comment: Under the hood it does or it should do but nevertheless you can always attach deviceready-listener.

Comment: I use ionic too and use to install plugins following command "ionic plugin add org.cordova..." to include it into platform-folder(android, ios).

Answer (score 1):

I also got trapped in this problem while using this plugin in my IONIC project.

Suggestion: Check the Android manifest file for File Read and Write permission.

Adding permission in the manifest can solve your problem.